# Using the N/Cache Module in SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to implement use of the N/cache module in a custom module to retain data across a bundle without it having to retrieve it from the remote source every time the data is needed. So I created this to get the cached data:

```
function data_GetCachedData() {
    var remoteInfo = null;
    require(['N/cache'], function (cache) {
        var rmtCache = cache.getCache({
                name : _REMOTE_CACHE_NAME
            ,   scope : cache.Scope.PROTECTED
        });
        remoteInfo = rmtCache.get({
                key : _REMOTE_CACHE_INDEX
            ,   loader : comms_ObtainRemoteData(params)
        });
    });
    return JSON.parse(remoteInfo || "{ }");
}
```

And I added this as the loader:

```
function comms_ObtainRemoteData(params) {
    var remoteData = null;
    /*
        make HTTPS calls to remote server to add values to 'remoteData'
    */
    
    require(['N/cache'], function (cache) {
        var rmtCache = cache.getCache({
                name : _REMOTE_CACHE_NAME
            ,   scope : cache.Scope.PROTECTED
        });
        ptCache.put({
                key : _REMOTE_CACHE_INDEX
            ,   value : remoteData.values
            ,   ttl : (18 * 60 * 60)
        });
    });
    
    return remoteData.values;
}
```

However, I added some logging and every time I call GetCachedData, it always triggers the loader. Is there something I'm missing with this? Because best as I can tell, this should be doing it just fine without having to always call the loader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is calling the remote function every time because you put parentheses after the loader function with a parameter. See this line `loader : comms_ObtainRemoteData(params)`
If you change that to `loader : comms_ObtainRemoteData` then you should be fine. The "loader" option of cache.get expects the name of a function, not the returned result of a function call.

Comment: For whatever reason I couldn't see how to make this work how you suggested, but then I realized that I was being a dummy. All I had to do was assign my value to a global variable before the loader could be called, and then have the loader look at that. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and had to switch the code.  Below is an example wiht your code:

```html
var rmtCache = cache.getCache({
                name : _REMOTE_CACHE_NAME
            ,   scope : cache.Scope.PROTECTED
        });
if (rmtCache==null){
      rmtCache = remoteData.values
ptCache.put({
                key : _REMOTE_CACHE_INDEX
            ,   value : rmtCache 
            ,   ttl : (18 * 60 * 60)
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As NetSuite clearly states

> A cached value is not guaranteed to stay in the cache for the full duration of the ttl value. The ttl value represents the maximum time that the cached value may be stored.

So may be due to resource crunch(may be due to multiple scripts/caches running in said account) or cache being invalidated as it was not used/requested in time, it could be reset/cleared out from memory.

Also, are you testing your script in test(Dev/Sandbox) environment? As testing environments have limited resources compared to Production environment.

I had faced the same issue multiple times in my dev environment, but it seems to work fine in Production environments.